# Can't include <I2S.h> on ESP32 on neither VSCode PIO nor Arduino IDE

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, platformio, i2s

I've tried to get my ESP32 LOLIN32 with Arduino framework working, but I can't even upload code to it. I'm including nothing but Arduino and I2S but it doesn't understand what I mean with I2S.
I have only written:

```
#include <I2S.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup(){

}

void loop(){

}
```

but it fails to compile and gives:

```
src\main.cpp:1:17: fatal error: I2S.h: No such file or directory
*************************************************************     
* Looking for I2S.h dependency? Check our library registry!       
*
* CLI  > platformio lib search "header:I2S.h"
* Web  > https://registry.platformio.org/search?q=header:I2S.h    
*
*************************************************************
```

Arduino IDE can't find it eather, I get the same error.

I've tried adding build_flags = -I and lib_deps in platform.ini:

```
[env:lolin32]
platform = espressif32
board = lolin32
framework = arduino
build_flags = -I include
lib_deps = 
    I2S
```

to no avail.

Comment: It should be `#include <driver/i2s.h>` to use the idf i2s driver.

Answer (score 0):

I2S.h was added to [arduino-esp32](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32) from version [2.0.3-RC1](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/2.0.3-RC1/libraries).
The OP does not describe the used version, but I guess it is older than the mentioned 2.0.3

**I suggest updating arduino-esp32**